# Performance difference between +=, ++, +

Tags: javascript

I created this test http://jsperf.com/loop-counter why is there such a difference between these three expressions.

Comment: Please post your code and results here, rather than expecting people to go to some other site and execute your code.

Comment: Why shouldn't there be a difference? The more operators there are the more things you can do with fewer lines of code. Just learn the differences and put them to good use to create beautiful code ;)

Comment: I was just learning about increment expression and thought i would run some tests through jsperf.com. I was quiet suprised by the results and wondered why they differ so much.

Comment: @Woltan thanks for the encouragement;) but its nice to have a deeper understanding about the operators.

Comment: ++var is fastest than var++ ! :)

Comment: You are quickly adding results to your page like this. Almost feels like fishing for tests and visitors...

Comment: @Erno - I find the result surprising, especially for Chrome, where I would expect simple, semantically identical code to perform the same.  I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @Alistair Laing go learn assembly. You'll see why the OPCODE for `+=` is more efficient as it takes less processor cycles.

Comment: @Erno no if you look at it I only made 1 revision and others have contributed. I am looking at how these operators work and I didn't release that I could use say ++i rather than i++

Comment: @Raynos - your comment about learning assembly in unhelpful.  It's up to the Javascript JIT instruction generation back-end to select the operation, and besides even in Intel asm, `OPERATION [memory-location], IMMEDIATE` isn't necessarily fast - it gets broken down into other operations in the CPU.

Comment: Please do not feel accused. I was nearly joking. I was amazed by the differences between Chrome and IE9. BTW: IE9 is no longer beta...

Comment: @andrewmu Having an appreciation of what happens at a very low level with these three operators will let you see the difference. You do this by learning assembly. Admittedly I didn't actaully realise his benchmark was wrong but that's beside the point.

Comment: please note that for small integers there's *usually* no difference in performance between pre- and postincrementation, because compiler turns var++ into ++var when it's not affecting anything else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because your test is wrong. you're reusing the same variable, so the larger it gets, the slower it is to increment. take a look at this: http://jsperf.com/loop-counter/6

this is how jsperf works - preparation code is run only once, before all tests.

Comment: well, in my tests the first code sample is no longer the fastest one, because each sample uses it's own variable to increment. i've tested it in fx4 and chrome 10.

Comment: Because in the original test, after the first test the second test uses the value of l_count, at that point not 0 anymore. The 'wildcard' version uses different variables, so all tests start with 0. In that case there is not much difference anymore. +1 for this answer

Comment: Thanks wildcard. I didn't realise that preparation code is only once but the results are still quiet interesting.

Comment: Aha! Ok, I just looked at the other versions.  Have +1 :)

Comment: @wildcard — There's no reason why the value should affect the speed of the operation.  To test this, I modified your setup to [start the second variable at 2^31](http://jsperf.com/loop-counter/11)… no change in speed.  Must be something to do with variable access?  This has me baffled.  :-)

Comment: @Ben, great insight! I would guess this is some crazy run-time optimisation done by JIT engine. In JS there's no such thing as integer, all numbers are floats by the rule. So maybe the engine is converting floats to ints (by multiplying them?) on its own?

Comment: @wildcard — I updated my test to include floats and large integers.  Now only the post-increment operator is slow, and only on floats and large integers.  I still can't figure out what's going on here… :-D

Comment: @Ben, actually my answer referred to your comment which has disappeared (the one about int limit and trying with 0.5) :>

Comment: @wildcard — Sorry about that!  I hoped you hadn't seen it yet; I didn't want an "I figured it out!" comment hanging around when clearly I hadn't.  ^.^

Comment: @Ben, now it totally makes sense. There shouldn't be any difference in performance between pre/post incrementation when dealing with small integers, as the compiler should be smart enough to change post- to preincrementation in such case (when it does not affect anything else). When you're using big ints or floats such optimisation can't happen.

Answer (score 2):

I tried running all three tests several times, and each time I reload the page, the first test I try is the fastest by far.

So I'm guessing there is some issue with the test being too short, i.e. the code that runs the tests is taking up most of the time.

Comment: I agree, I added a revision /3 that changed the order of tests and the first test 'won' again...

Comment: its not a matter of test being to short, but a variable being reused. my answer explains it a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434084/performance-difference-between/5434346#5434346

Answer (score 2):

If this is not a *rhetorical question* and you actually want an aswer then: becuse of how people have written the JS engine in the browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of what the program is doing behind the scenes:

**l_count += 1;** This adds the number 1 to the variable.

**l_count = l_count + 1;** This calls the variable l_count, reads it, adds 1 to the result, and passes that back to l_count.

**l_count++;** This adds 1 to the variable after the line is run. So the value is stored in another temporary variable while the line is done, then the value is returned, added 1 and saved back to the original value.

Comment: it would totally make sense, but then ++x should be faster too. and it's not: http://jsperf.com/loop-counter/5

Comment: It's just a small difference, probably due to memory allocations and thread time-slices. just change the order between the last 2. put ++l_count before l_count++ .... you could barely notice the difference. it's just 1 op code difference after all. the fact that it saves a temporary variable to hold the result is what makes  the real difference

Comment: The link wasn't really relevant to the question anyway. I'll remove it.

Comment: right, figured it out elsewhere (see comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434084/performance-difference-between/5434346#5434346) - there's no difference in performance between post and preincrementation if you're dealing with small integers, as the compiler is smart enough to make it's own optimisations and turn post- into preincrementation when it's possible.